# Should I use 'have' or 'get' in this sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I need to ask my colleague to delete an email account from a system. Which sentence is more appropriate for the above context?.

1. Please have the account deleted from AD
2. Please get the account deleted from AD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please have the account deleted from AD** sounds more proper.

Comment: Can you please tell me the difference between these two sentences?

Comment: Get is more like "acquire" or "achieve", so from what I can tell for the context, you want the amount to undergo deletion, which is more in line with the definition of "have. Out of curiosity, is your colleague deleting the account, or is he asking someone to delete the account? Your sentences both imply that your colleague is not *directly* deleting the account, but rather having someone else do it.

Comment: My colleague is not deleting the account but is asking someone to do it

Comment: Awesome then the sentence I suggested will work perfect.